# Why there is a colon in some http header?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, http

[image]

I'm using Chrome, don't know why some headers in request headers have a colon prefix such as ":method", ":path", while there is no colon prefix in some other headers, what's the point to add a colon prefix for a header, doesn it have a special meaning?

Comment: These are not HTTP headers. My guess is that this program uses the colon to differentiate information like the method or scheme from headers.

Answer (score 5):

> These are HTTP/2 pseudo-headers that apply to requests and responses
> within an HTTP/2 stream. HTTP/2 creates a single persistent connection
> from each distinct origin end-point to a server. That connection
> transmits multiple requests and responses to and from the end-point;
> these are parsed into "frames" and transmitted as "streams". HTTP/2
> can interleave frames from multiple request and response streams
> simultaneously to get huge performance benefits. [intro to http/2](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/http2)
>
> Pseudo-headers apply to streams; a different set of headers apply to
> the connection itself. Four pseudo-headers are defined for requests:
> :method, :scheme, :authority, and :path. No others are allowed. These
> 4 must be included in every request header block and they must precede
> any other headers:
>
> "All pseudo-header fields MUST appear in the header block before
> regular header fields. Any request or response that contains a
> pseudo-header field that appears in a header block after a regular
> header field MUST be treated as malformed (Section 8.1.2.6)." [http2
> spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59776597 by HieroB